# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.XML.toJSONObject

Tags: xml, json, org.json

Aim: to parse XML to JSON:
i have imported json-org.jar to parse XML to JSON.
it was fine working with simple java project but during Android  its gives ERROR:

```
String stringxml="<item><title>Clinton slams Russia, China over Syria</title></item>";
JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(stringxml);
org.json.JSONObject j = org.json.XML.toJSONObject(stringxml);
String json = j.toString();
```

I have got the Error in DDMS:
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.json.XML.toJSONObject
    at org.json.XML.toJSONObject(XML.java:282)

Comment: This generally means that the JARs you compiled with are different from the JARs you're running with.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = null;           
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("XXX.xml");

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF8");
        Reader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
        int ch;
        while ((ch = in.read()) > -1) {
             buffer.append((char)ch);
        }
        in.close();

        String xml = buffer.toString();

        //System.out.println("xml = " + xml);


        jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
```